# Any rough comparison of QPS between MySQL and other NoSQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

Assuming the queries are for a social network website. The database runs on a single machine. If MySQL has about ~10,000 QPS. What will be the general QPS for a NoSQL database? Assuming both MySQL and NoSQL databases have a proper index.

Comment: What is your benchmark. If you've got 10KQPS on MySQL (seem a touch low -untuned? Low spec)? can't you run the same on NoSQL? I wouldn't expect a major difference unless theres a specific query type that is especially got for one of the database implementaitons.

Comment: I think the same as you. I just wondering whether MySQL has a slight advantage because of years' optimization. Most NoSQL databases have a short history.

Comment: Probably. And NoSQL dbs have had a short time to take advantage of SQL development and tack a "No" word in front (comedy intended) :-)